# Range.Find on Dates with custom number format

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the relevant parts of my code I'm having trouble with.

```
Sub Find_Target()

Dim DayNum As Long
Dim TargetName As String
Dim TargetDay As Range
Dim found As Variant

DayNum = Cells(1, 9)

Set TargetDay = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3-2015").Range("A1:B440")
TargetDay.Activate

Set found = TargetDay.Find(DayNum, LookIn:=xlValues)

If found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing found!"
Else
    TargetDay.Select
End If
End Sub
```

Column A contains a mix of merged and unmerged cells. Cells(1, 9) contains a date in general format. Periodically in column A/B will be a merged cell containing that same number, but in custom number format "dddd". The find command works if I change the number format to general, but otherwise found is Nothing.

I've tried playing with the FindFormat option, but didn't have any luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit unclear from the question, so I'm assuming that you have a number in cell I1 and you want to find the first cell with on the same day of the month.  Assuming that's the case, you can just loop through the range and compare against the day directly:

```
Sub Find_Target()
    Dim DayNum As Long
    Dim TargetDay As Range
    Dim found As Range

    DayNum = Cells(1, 9)

    Set TargetDay = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3-2015").Range("A1:B440")

    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    For row = 1 To TargetDay.Rows.Count
        For col = 1 To TargetDay.Columns.Count
            If IsDate(TargetDay.Cells(row, col).Value) Then
                If Day(CDate(TargetDay.Cells(row, col).Value)) = DayNum Then
                    Set found = TargetDay.Cells(row, col)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next col
        If Not found Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next row

    If found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found!"
    Else
        found.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

If I1 is something else, it should be trivial to modify - the key is explicitly treating the cell values as dates in VBA.

Comment: I tried this (slightly modified, changed the ends of the For loops to 500 and 2, respectively), but I get an error of Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" at "If Day(CDate(TargetDay.Cells(row, col).Value)) = DayNum Then"

Also, with 500 rows and 2 columns like, will this cause the function to be heavily resource intensive?

Comment: @EaterOfFromage - Unfortunately I can't replicate an error 91 at all with the code above, even if I intentionally over-run the bounds of the Range (see next comment).  The only error I could coax out was an error 13 (type mismatch) if I put data that couldn't be cast to a Date inside the target range (fixed above). Did your change effect this line: `Set TargetDay = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3-2015").Range("A1:B440")`?

Comment: @EaterOfFromage - Regarding the For loops - the bounds of the range get set with "A1:B440", so there isn't any reason to hard code the loop conditions - with `.Rows.Count` and `.Columns.Count` it will traverse whatever range you put in the `Set TargetDay` line.

Comment: I finally got this to work! I had some issues for a while with types being mismatched (The cells in Columns A and B were a mix of Dates, Text, Times, and Blanks). I also realized I'd been misleading in my language, the DayNum variable was in DateValue format, so I had to compare DayNum to DateValue(TargetDay.Cells(row,col).Value)). Thanks for taking me down the right path though, works like a charm now!

Comment: Oh sorry, just missed your comments. I realized the error 91 was a silly error I made, I commented out the Set TargetDay line by accident. And thanks for the tip on the .Rows.Count, that makes sense now.

Comment: @EaterOfFromage - Glad it worked for you - I missed your question about performance above - I tested it with 10,000 rows and no matches, still finished in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.Find` for `LookAt:=xlFormulas` and look for a Date type var, not a Long. Throw the following at your data.

```
Sub Find_Target()
    Dim iDayNum As Long, sDayNum As String, dDayNum As Date
    Dim foundI As Variant, foundS As Variant, foundD As Variant
    Dim TargetDay As Range

    iDayNum = Cells(1, 9)
    sDayNum = Format(Cells(1, 9), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    dDayNum = Cells(1, 9)  'I might even use CDate(Cells(1, 9).Value) as a reminder

    Set TargetDay = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3-2015").Range("A1:B440")

    Set foundI = TargetDay.Find(iDayNum, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set foundS = TargetDay.Find(sDayNum, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set foundD = TargetDay.Find(dDayNum, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If foundI Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "As a Long - Nothing found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "As a Long - Found!"
    End If
    If foundS Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "As a String - Nothing found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "As a String - Found!"
    End If
    If foundD Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "As a Date - Nothing found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "As a Date - Found!"
    End If
End Sub
```

You should have no problem finding the matching date var no matter whether it is formatted as *dddd* or anything else.

Comment: I tried this solution and found that they all returned nothing. It doesn't seem like changing the data type makes any difference to the result. I tried sDayNum = Format(Cells(1, 9), "mm/dd/yyyy") as sDayNum = Format(Cells(1, 9), "dddd") and had no results found either.

Comment: @EaterOfFromage - If that didn't work for you then I strongly suspect that the dates may actually be datetimes, all with different times which essentially changes their value. Honestly, I do test thoroughly before posting. See [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Find_dddd_from_General.xlsb) for my sample.

Comment: Oh! I didn't think it would make a difference, but I think the problem may be that the cells with dates in them are determined with a formula. Not all of the cells in that column are though. So LookIn:=xlFormulas may be getting confused on my sheet.

Comment: @EaterOfFromage - If the dates are returned by formula then you will have to use a string type var formatted as *dddd* and `LookIn:=xlValues`. Revist my sample link for a second `Find_Target2` as example. Obviously, the problem with this would be more than a single week's worth of data as you would have two or more possible matches depending on the number of weeks involved. You might want to try a VBA-based single column Vlookup or Index/Match instead.

Comment: I managed to sort it out with Comintern's solution and some modifcations. My first time on the site or really collaborated with anyone about VBA, so I clearly have a few things to learn about how to phrase things and what qualifies as important haha. Thanks!